# VBA: Debug.Print without newline?

Tags: vba, debugging, newline

For debugging in VBA, I have several `Debug.Print` statements throughout my code.  For a line-parsing block, I'd like to print the line, and output any flags **inline** with the line, without having multiple `Debug.Print sFlag & sLine` statements throughout the many if/elseif/else blocks.

Is there a way, within VBA, to suppress the newline at the end of a `Debug.Print` statement?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It turns out you can easily do this by simply adding a semicolon to the end of your `Debug.Print` statement.  Like so:

```
While oExec.StdOut.AtEndOfStream = False
   sLine = oExec.StdOut.ReadLine
   If bInFileSystem Then
      If AnalyzeFileSystemLine(sLine) = False Then
         Debug.Print "[FSERR]: ";
      End If
   ElseIf bInWASCheck Then
      If AnalyzeWASLine(sLine) = False Then
         Debug.Print "[WASERR]: ";
      End If
   End If

   Debug.Print sLine
Wend
```

So, some sample output will be:

```
test text things look good!
[FSERR]: uh oh this file system is at 90% capacity!
some more good looking text :)
[WASERR]: oh no an app server is down!
```

Comment: Quite right.  You could also put `Debug.Print` at very bottom, under `Wend`.  Then close the line above `Wend` with a semi-colon.  Same result.